# Facebook Realtime API + Rails + POST not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook-graph-api, koala

I'm subscribing to Facebook's Realtime API (using the Koala gem, etc.) to get data every time the pages that a user manages, changes...

For some reason, I do not receive any POST data from Facebook, but:

1.) The test 'GET' method works fine through Facebook
2.) When I POST from a different source, it works fine.
3.) The user has granted the `manage_pages` permissions
4.) The callback url is public - (i.e. why step 1 works)

Here's the code from the controller that handles the requests from Facebook:

```
class RealtimeupdatesController < ApplicationController

  def verify
      if request.request_method == "GET"
        challenge = Koala::Facebook::RealtimeUpdates.meet_challenge(params,'testtoken')
        if(challenge)
          render :text => challenge
        else
          render :text => 'Failed to authorize facebook challenge request'
        end
      #elsif request.request_method == "POST"
      else
        Merchant.create(:email => "user@user.com")
      end
  end

end
```